# During airshows, how common is it to fly armed with (inert?) missiles?

Tags: fighter, missiles, airshow

I notices that these three [Su-35s were armed with missiles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCIsLc-rdMo) during an airshow. At the 1-min mark, you can clearly see that jet #38 has 2 missiles under each wing as well as a bomb / (spare fuel tank?) and that jet #3 has a missile under at least 1 wing. At 5:25, that jet has 3 missiles. etc.

I assume these are all inert, non-explosive? And used to prove the Super-Flanker is still super-manuverable even when armed?

Is this common practice for all air forces to demonstrate the performance of their best jets even when armed? I've thought of airshows as a demonstration to "the people" where you try to impress them with aerobatics and get them to clap and appreciate how much money is being spent on the air force. Thus, why the weapons?

Of course, if Russia were trying to get Erdogan to switch to the Sukoi family, then you must demo fully armed jets.